# Differences in Python's packed binary data size among platforms?

Tags: python, multiplatform

I'm trying to 'unpack' (using Python's struct module) a bytearray to multiple variables, using a formatted string:

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) = unpack('HHHHHBBL', my_byte_array)
```

I expect (when I read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)) that:

- *a* through *e* will be an *unsigned short* (of a size 2 bytes each)
- *f* and *g* will be an *unsigned char* (with a size of 1 byte each)
- *h* will be an *unsigned long* (with a size of of 8 bytes)

When I run this on my Windows 10 machine, this is exactly what I get.

On my other two machines with Mac OS X and Manjaro Linux (all three have Python 3.7 installed), I will get an error stating:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 24 bytes
```

When I run the following, the output is the same on all three machines

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> calcsize('H')
2
>>> calcsize('B')
1
>>> calcsize('L')
8
```

But when I run the following:

```
>>> calcsize('HHHHHBBL')
```

The Output on my Windows machine is *16*, but on the other two systems *24*. Which seems strange to me, what is going on here?

And how should I use *struct.unpack* in a multiplatform environment?

Comment: You have to start your `struct` format string with one of the standard byte order/size/alignment indicators (usually `<` or `>`) in order to get any sort of cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Ah many thanks, that was it! :) @jasonharper. Can you add the comment as an answer, so I can mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jasonharper:

> You have to start your `struct` format string with one of the standard byte order/size/alignment indicators (usually `<` or `>`) in order to get any sort of cross-platform compatibility